# Can I use temporary stat bonuses to obtain locked levelling perks in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I am playing a low Charisma character, but I really want the Intimidation perk.  I know you can train your S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats up, and that there's certain items such as the SPECIAL book, and Bobbleheads which give permanent stat buffs, but what if I get a *temporary* level 10 Charisma through clothing and chems etc?

Would I be able to gain access to the full Charisma tree when levelling up?

Secondary related question: When you do level up, do you HAVE to allocate a point immediately?  Or can you exit out, pop a Mentat, then go back in and choose a perk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't get any added "soft boost" from items as part of the stat requirements in the perks chart.

So if you popped a mentat or put on a special hat, these things will not effect your available perks in the perk chart.

You don't have to allocate a point immediately though either, you can store points but will be continually reminded by the game "You leveled up! Spend your points in the Perk Chart!"

Comment: actually that reminder goes away after a while, I often save a perk or two so I can assign it to several important ones as soon as I reach the level required for them.

Comment: In my low Int playthrough I also wanted the Science! perk for customization reasons but also had Idiot Savant. Definitely worth saving and raising Int all in one go, so you can maximize the chances of Idiot Savant kicking in.

Comment: Awesome!  Not really, but my questions are answered and now I must rethink my character build haha.  Maybe knock a few points from Agility and Perception and add to Charisma.  Thanks!